# JDBC access to Azure database

Tags: ios, azure

Using the Azure SDK for iOS, I have an app writing to the database. I'm now trying to configure a query using ODBC and Excel. As I'm on a Mac, only JDBC is an option.

```
JDBC connection only gives "Network error IOException: Connection refused"
```

I have setup up the Azure firewall settings for the machine IP.

Anyone with any Azure/iOS dev experience?

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Please use [Microsoft JDBC Driver](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245496) and make sure your connection string conforms SQL Azure Connection string. Required properties are:

- Encrypt=True
- Trusted_Connection=false
- Database=[database name]

You shall have no issues with this setup.